# How to access a file from Docker image from the host using Google Clould Build

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I would like to move node_modules.zip which is inside the Docker image to the static folder found within the directory.

Currently, my cloudbuild.yaml looks as follows:

```
  - id: package_js
    name: gcr.io/numom-57642/test4:latest
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    waitFor: ['-']
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        mv node_modules.zip static/
```

When I run cloud-build-local I get an error:

```
Step #1 - "package_js": mv: cannot stat 'node_modules.zip': No such file or directory
```

How can I access node_modules.zip which is part of the Docker Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm.... interesting.

I think you're on the right path.

You should be able to copy the file into the default mounted `/workspace` or a newly mounted volume:

```
- id: package_js
  name: gcr.io/numom-57642/test4:latest
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  volumes:
  - name: 'scratch'
    path: '/scratch'
  args:
  - -c
  - |
    cp node_modules.zip /workspace
    cp node_modules.zip /scratch
```

And then:

```
- id: check
  name: busybox
  volumes:
  - name: 'scratch'
    path: '/scratch'
  args:
  - |
    ls -l /workspace
    ls -l /scratch
```

Using `/workspace` is easier as you needn't mount volumes but using `/scratch` is more explicit.

Comment: node_modules is inside the image. Shouldn't it be 'cp /workspace/node_modules.zip stastic'

Comment: Right! You need to get the zip out of a container running the image and onto a volume that's persisted by Cloud Build between steps. I eyeballed the solution. If it didn't work, I'll try it tomorrow and correct it.

Comment: If `/workspace` didn't work, `/scratch` should have. IIRC `/workspace` is mounted too but that's just a hunch.